# Drag Marker to return the latitude and longitude of that location in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm new to google maps in android.
I want a functionality like, on the page it has to display the map and there has to be a marker in the map and the map has to be draggable and by dragging it has to display the dragged location's latitude and longitude..
Can anyone plz help me in solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/12/move-marker-on-mapview.html) here, that does just that.

---

Override `onTouchEvent()`

```
if (Action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
if(!moveMap)
{
    Projection proj = myMapView.getProjection();
    GeoPoint loc = proj.fromPixels((int)arg0.getX(), (int)arg0.getY());

    //remove the last marker
    myMapView.getOverlays().remove(0);

    centerLocation(loc);
}
```

---

```
else if (Action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
moveMap = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I successfully implemented the above tutorial and now i am getting the latitude and longitude. I also wanted the address of that particular latitude and longitude to be loaded? How can i get the address of this corresponding latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to get dragged position and details of marker.

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            Log.d(TAG, "latitude : "+ marker.getPosition().latitude);
            marker.setSnippet(marker.getPosition().latitude);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        }

    });
```